# How can I display voltage?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, lcd

I want to display voltage ranging from 0-24V on an LCD.

We can use an analog to digital converter but the range I need is much bigger to compare with.

How do I connect it without any microcontroller?

Comment: Do you know about voltage dividers? And you need a microcontroller.

Comment: Something like this? https://www.amazon.com/CrocSee-Display-Voltmeter-Motorcycle-Calibratable/dp/B086W91N43  search for *lcd panel meter*

Comment: *I want to display voltage ranging from 0-24V on an LCD.* Hmm, sounds like exactly what a multimeter does. There are cheap ones ( $10 or less) that can do the job. Explain why you're trying to make your own when a ready-to-use solution exists?

Comment: the title of your post suggests that you have a problem with displaying text ... the body of your post suggests that you have a problem with measuring voltage ...... so, which is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is with a voltmeter module.

If you don't like that, then you could build your own with purpose made [digital voltmeter IC](https://www.homemade-circuits.com/make-this-simple-digital-voltmeter/) that includes the ADC and the display drivers - it looks like this:

[image]
<sub>That's an LED version.  There's a similar chip to drive LCDs.</sub>

If you don't like that, then you could build your own using a box full of 7400 or 4000 series ICs to convert the (parallel) binary output of the ADC to drive a display.

You'll have to do a fair bit of analog and digital design to get a working device.

If you use a microprocessor, you do a little analog design to get the signal into the processor, then write a little software to put the voltage on a display using standard, easily available components.

If all you want is to display the voltage, you're probably better off with a voltmeter module.

If you need to do anything else with the measured value, then you are probably better off going the microprocessor route.

If you are a glutton for punishment, you could implement the whole thing in about shoe box size using a pile of 4000 and/or 7400 series ICs.

Comment: That is one of the most horrible electronics websites I've seen, and that's a bit of an accomplishment. The correct part number for LED drive (the one shown in that 'schematic') is ICL7107. ICL7106 is the LCD version and has the backplane drive on pin 21.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany:   Yep.  We've gotten a few questions in the past from people who read a post on that site, then asked for help here.